# How to trim a rendering of a json object of its extra spacing

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm rendering a json object in angular inside of a . How can I remove the extra spaces before and after the output? Right now, it looks like this:

[image: json obj in angular with extra space padding]

I want it to look like:

Js: `$scope.someObj = { hello: 'world' };`

Html: `<pre>{{someObj | json}}</pre>`

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ripitimeqe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from the indentation of the `<pre>` element.  You will just have to remove that spacing:

```
<pre>{{someObj | json}}</pre>
```

vs.

```
<pre>
    {{someObj | json}}
</pre>
```